# XCode 4.2 can't rebuild my simple Object C project with 64-bit, 32-bit success?

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4.2

I am a beginner of Objective C and XCode. I use Mac os X Lion and XCode 4.2. first, I create a project, command line tool, type is fundation. it generate a 'hello world' project.
I build it use command + B and run it by command + R.
it output "hello world" on console output.
when I change the code, and build it again, but it is always output "Hello World"...
this is my new code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

BOOL CompareInt( int lhs, int rhs ); 
void DumpBOOL( BOOL bValue );

BOOL CompareInt( int lhs, int rhs ) { return lhs == rhs; }

void DumpBOOL( BOOL bValue ) {
    if( bValue == YES )
    {
        NSLog( @"YES" );
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"NO" );
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    DumpBOOL( CompareInt(100, 1000) );

    @autoreleasepool 
    {    
        // insert code here...
        NSLog( @"Hello, World!!!!");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

if I change the setting on the left, change "my Mac 64-bit" to "My Mac 32-bit", it work success.
   so, I want to know how to solve it with 64bit setting.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I recreated this project, and it's ok now.
I don't know the reason for the problem!.